# How to order a menu list by price in accending order

Tags: jquery, wordpress, list

I have a WP site that lists menu items, I need a script that will re-arrange the list into acceding price.  The problem is that there are multiple lists on the page and the list contains divs.

JS fiddle below
http://jsfiddle.net/msZ98/89/ **updated jsfiddle**

```
<div class="grid2column">
<div id="menu-widget-no-link-2" class="widget menu-widget menu-items-no-link">
     <h3 class="header-underline">Vegetarian starters</h3>  
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Lounge mix vegetarian platter*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£9.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">combination of starters including onion bhaji, samosa, crispy baji, chilli paneer and mogo</div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Garlic chilli mushroom*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£5.50</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Stir firied mushroom with green chilli, capsicum, onion, tomato and spring onion</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Paneer tikka*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£6.50</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Tandoor cooked Indian cheese chunks marinated in a blend of spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Vegetable momo*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£5.75</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Steamed dumplings stuffed with vegetables mince and a blend of Nepali spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Crispy bhindi *</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£4.75</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Crispy fried okra marinated in special spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Crispy bhaji *</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£4.25</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Sliced potato dipped in spicy batter and deep fried</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Aloo papdi chaat *</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£3.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Baby potato and chick pea salad served with yoghurt and tamarind chutney</div>
        </li>

        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Vegetable samosa</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£3.00</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Popular Indian savoury pastry filled with vegetables and spices</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu-spacer"></div>
<div id="menu-widget-no-link-4" class="widget menu-widget menu-items-no-link">
     <h3 class="header-underline">Non vegetarian starters</h3>  
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Tandoor Jhinga lasoni**</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£11.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Tandoor cooked succulent king prawns marinated in garlic, coriander and spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Ajwani Fish tikka*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£7.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Succulent pieces of fish marinated in ajwani and spices and tandoor cooked</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Lamb chops**</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£4.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Lamb chops marinated in yoghurt and spices and tandoor cooked</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Chicken/Lamb chilli**</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£6.95/7.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Stir fried boneless chicken or lamb with green chilli, capsicum, onion, tomato and spring onion</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Chicken/Lamb momo**</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£5.95/6.25</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Steamed dumplings stuffed with chicken or lamb mince and Nepali spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Murg tikka*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£6.25</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Succulent pieces of boneless chicken breast marinated in spices and tandoor cooked</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Murg Tandoori *</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£5.95</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Tandoor cooked chicken on the bone marinated in freshly ground spices</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Peri Peri wings*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£5.75</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Chicken wings marinated in special peri peri sauce and tandoor cooked</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Chicken Pakora**</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£4.50</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Deep fired chicken chunks marinated in spices and special batter</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid2column">Lamb samosa*</div>
            <div class="grid2column lastcolumn">£3.50</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="item-description-menu">Cripsy Indian savoury pastry filled with minced lamb and spices</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu-spacer"></div>
```

Comment: The code you post isn't the same structure as your fiddle.

Comment: the HTML in the fiddle

Comment: It is still the same link

Comment: sorry, didnt see that.  changed

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching your problem incorrectly. You are trying to parse your HTML to get your price and then sort and move them. `What will happen when you change the style of your page ?`

There are a lot of ways to tackle your problem. My approach is this:

1. Index your list items by giving them Id.
2. Keep a list of price and id in an array.
3. Sort that array.
4. Restructure your page based on the sorted list.

Below is the javascript that shows how to do this. [I also made this **JSFIDDLE** link which shows the result.](https://jsfiddle.net/hg2d1j9s/) Please note here that I have only done your "vegetarian" list part. If you understand my code, doing the same for your non-veg part will be a piece of cake.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sPrice").click(function() {
            var vegPrice = [
                {key: 9.95, value: "1"},
                {key: 5.50, value: "2"},
                {key: 6.50, value: "3"},
                {key: 5.75, value: "4"},
                {key: 4.75, value: "5"},
                {key: 4.25, value: "6"},
                {key: 3.95, value: "7"},
                {key: 3.00, value: "8"}
            ];

            var sortedVegPrice = vegPrice.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.key >= b.key;
            });

            var lastInjected = "vegmenu";
            $.each(sortedVegPrice, function( index, value ) {
                $("#" + value.value).insertAfter($("#" + lastInjected));
                lastInjected = value.value;
            });
    });
});
```

BTW I can tell from your menu that you are an indian (I am too) and your list of items made me hungry ^_^